# Semi-transparent mesh background with opaque buttons

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I have read time and again that if you make a UIView transparent, it affects all its subviews, including buttons, etc. I want the background of my UIView to be semi-transparent (alpha=.5 perhaps) and to be made of a specific image pattern that repeats itself, but I want the buttons in that view to be completely opaque. I could separate the buttons into separate views, but that doesn't seem efficient. What is the best approach here? Regarding a mesh background, if I make a pattern I like, is this all that is required:

```
self.view.backgroundColor= [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.jpg"]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not open your image in an image editor and save it as a 50% transparent image?

Comment: I suppose that is an obvious suggestions, but suppose you are working with an image you do not wish to edit, and need to do this programmatically? (perhaps the same image file is used elsewhere, for instance)

Comment: Perhaps instead of a background, add the image as a subview with alpha:0.5 behind the buttons and other subviews?